# Getting used indices of indexed terms in a sympy sum

Tags: sympy

Say I have variables `x` and `y` which are indexed

```
from sympy.tensor import IndexedBase
x = IndexedBase('x')`
```

And I have an expression like `e = x[1] y[2] + x[5] y[10]`
. I want to find all indices used by each of `x` and `y`. I'm looking for a function which might work like this: `e.indices(y) = [2, 10]` and `e.indicies(x) = [1, 5]`

Is there a way I can iterate through the terms `x[i] y[j]`? And if so, is there a way to split a product into terms and for each of those pull out which letter is being used and which index appears?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should get you headed in the right direction:

```
>>> from sympy.tensor import IndexedBase, Indexed
>>> from sympy import sift
>>> x = IndexedBase('x')
>>> y = IndexedBase('y')
>>> e = x[1]* y[2] + x[5]* y[10]
>>> e.atoms(IndexedBase)
set([y, x])
>>> e.atoms(Indexed)
set([x[5], y[10], x[1], y[2]])
>>> sifted = sift(_,lambda i: i.base)
>>> sifted[x]
[x[5], x[1]]
>>> sifted[y]
[y[10], y[2]]
>>> [i.indices for i in _]
[(10,), (2,)]
>>> flatten(_)
[10, 2]
```

Comment: I think you forgot to import `Indexed`, but thanks I'll try this

Comment: Oh and I looked up `sift` as well which is in `sympy.utilities.iterables.sift`

Comment: (I added those in, above, for posterity.)